# iOS App Distribution and Deployment Target

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store

I need to build app for distribution via app store.

Application is tested and working on `iOS 5.0, 5.1 and 6.0`.

Do I need to build different archives for each iOS version (change `iOS Deployment Target` setting for each build)?

Is there any difference to compiled output when I change `iOS Deployment Target` setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the *SDK version* you are using is **highest iOS version** it will run and *Deployment Target* is the **lowest**.

So set your *Deployment Target* to 5.0, compile using iOS SDK 6.0 (you don't have any other option, though) and that's it. Submit to the App Store.

I don't know if there are some differences in binary when changing *Deployment Target*, but there are some during compilation for sure. For example when you set it to iOS 6, you may get deprecation warnings from the latest API changes.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to do one build with the lowest iOS version you want to support, and then you go through all the upload process.